Why absolute positoned elements don't scroll with the content?
I see some code in a tutorial like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="like-button">❤️ Like</button>

  <p>some random text</p>
</body>

.like-button
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

However, when I scroll the page (I've removed some long text for simplicity in the posted code), the like button doesn't scroll with the content. I know using position: fixed can solve the issue, but I still wonder: since the like button's position is relative to the viewport, and the viewport is changing when scrolling, why doesn't the button move accordingly?

Absolute positioning is relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, not to the viewport. In case you don't have positioned ancestors, it will be relative to the body, which for very long pages goes off the viewport. Fixed positioning is relative to the viewport.

@BackSlash it won't be relative to the body but to the "initial containing block": https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details (if it was the body, it won't be place at the bottom of the page)

I get it now. Thank you all!
